# Condensing a data frame using multiple arguments from certain variables

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr

I'm looking to condense a data frame based on various arguments from multiple variables and I'm not quite sure on how to achieve it in the easiest way possible. I'm thinking it's going to need some kind of personalised function but I don't have much experience in writing functions.

Basically, my data frame currently looks like this:

```
chainID     teamID        statID        startType       endType        

1           Team A     Effective Pass      TO              TO
1           Team A     Effective Pass      TO              TO
1           Team A     Effective Pass      TO              TO
1           Team A     Effective Pass      TO              TO
1           Team A     Ineffective Pass    TO              TO
2           Team B     Effective Pass      TO              SH
2           Team B     Entry               TO              SH
2           Team B     Effective Pass      TO              SH
2           Team B     Shot                TO              SH
3           Team A     Effective Pass      ST              TO
3           Team A     Entry               ST              TO
3           Team A     Ineffective Pass    ST              TO
4           Team B     Effective Pass      TO              ST
4           Team B     Effective Pass      TO              ST
4           Team B     Ineffective Pass    TO              ST
5           Team A     Effective Pass      TO              SH
5           Team A     Entry               TO              SH
5           Team A     Goal                TO              SH
6           Team B     Effective Pass      CB              TO
6           Team B     Effective Pass      CB              TO
6           Team B     Ineffective Pass    CB              TO
7           Team A     Effective Pass      TO              ST
7           Team A     Ineffective Pass    TO              ST
```

What I'm looking to do is whenever the word `Entry` appears in the `statID` column for any `chainID`, I want to keep that row and the last row for that `chainID` whilst removing all the other rows for that particular `chainID` (see chainID 2 and 5). In addition, what I also need is that if a chainID includes Entry in the statID but the last row in that particular chainID doesn't end in Goal or Shot then I want the next chainID to remain in the data set as seen in my example with chainID 3 and 4. Then the function continues to look for Entry occurrences per chainID as it did in the beginning.
E.g.

```
chainID     teamID        statID        startType       endType        

2           Team B     Entry               TO              SH
2           Team B     Shot                TO              SH
3           Team A     Entry               ST              TO
3           Team A     Ineffective Pass    ST              TO
4           Team B     Effective Pass      TO              ST
4           Team B     Effective Pass      TO              ST
4           Team B     Ineffective Pass    TO              ST
5           Team A     Entry               TO              SH
5           Team A     Goal                TO              SH
```

Comment: `chainID = 4` doesn't have `Entry` still the rows are selected?

Comment: Yes as `chainID = 3` includes an `Entry`, but doesn't end in `Goal` or `Shot` so I need the following `chainID` (#4) to remain in the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is divided into two functions. First function `select_rows`, selects the rows from each group based on presence of `"Entry"`. The second function `select_groups` finds out the groups which doesn't end in `"Goal"` or `"Shot"`.

```
library(dplyr)

select_rows <- function(anyEntry, statID) {
   #If anyEntry value is not 0
   if(anyEntry[1L]) { 
      #If the last value is either "Goal" or "Shot" select "Entry" row and last row
      #else select all the rows from "Entry" to last row. 
      if(last(statID) %in% c("Goal", "Shot")) c(anyEntry[1L], length(anyEntry)) 
         else anyEntry[1L] : length(anyEntry) 
     } else 0
}

select_groups <- function(anyEntry, statID) {
    anyEntry[1L] & !last(statID) %in% c("Goal", "Shot")
}
```

We create `anyEntry` column which has the row number in the group where the first `"Entry"` value is present or 0 otherwise. We apply `select_rows` and `select_groups` function separately and bind the columns.

```
df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(chainID) %>%
        mutate(anyEntry = which.max(statID == "Entry") * any(statID == "Entry"))

Ids <- df1 %>%
         summarise(newEntry = select_groups(anyEntry, statID)) %>%
         filter(newEntry) %>% pull(chainID)

df1 %>%
  slice(select_rows(anyEntry, statID)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(chainID %in% (Ids + 1))) %>%
  select(-anyEntry) %>%
  arrange(chainID)

#   chainID teamID statID    startType  endType
#     <int> <fct>  <fct>        <fct>     <fct>  
#1       2 TeamB  Entry           TO        SH     
#2       2 TeamB  Shot            TO        SH     
#3       3 TeamA  Entry           ST        TO     
#4       3 TeamA  IneffectivePass ST        TO     
#5       4 TeamB  EffectivePass   TO        ST     
#6       4 TeamB  EffectivePass   TO        ST     
#7       4 TeamB  IneffectivePass TO        ST     
#8       5 TeamB  Entry           TO        SH     
#9       5 TeamB  Goal            TO        SH
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ronak! I'm sorry for the error in my example, it has since been edited. I didn't explain the second part to my problem well. The solution you have provided address the first part of my problem which is great! What I also need is that if a `chainID` includes `Entry` in the `statID` but the last row in that particular `chainID` doesn't end in `Goal` or `Shot` then I want the next chainID to remain in the data set as seen in my example with chainID 3 and 4. Then the function continues to look for `Entry` occurrences per `chainID` as it did in the beginning.

Comment: @I.DiDomenico updated the answer accordingly. See if it works now.

Comment: I'm getting an error when running the script creating the `Ids` data frame. The errors states the following - `Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'chainID' not found`

Comment: @I.DiDomenico Do you have some different name in the dataframe instead of `chainID` ? Maybe `ChainID` or `chainId` or something else? Also `Ids` is not a dataframe it is a numeric vector.

Comment: I've also noticed that when I create the anyEntry column and it displays the row number where the first `Entry` occurs it repeats the same number and doesn't display a 0

Comment: yes, it is supposed to have the same number for each group i.e `chainID`. For each group it will either have row number where first entry occurs or if entry is not present it will have 0 for all the rows in that group.

Comment: So each group has the same number? At this stage it's repeating the same number for the entire data set.

Comment: I just noticed that my `chainID` variable is a `factor` with only `1 level` as opposed to the total number of `chainID` variations, which might explain why the creation of the `anyEntry` column is returning the same number for the entire data set

Comment: If you have only one unique `chainID` in the entire dataset then all the `anyEntry` column would have the same number of values but then all those rules would be meaningless? "If chainID has Entry............." etc etc?

Comment: I'm currently troubleshooting to find out why my `chainID` only has 1 factor level despite the fact that there are 255 different `chainID` in the data set. The  functions you have provided should work once that problem is address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195775/discussion-between-i-di-domenico-and-ronak-shah).